# Jawr fails with the css property content

Tags: css, tomcat, jawr, contentproperty

In my css I have a selector like this

```
a[href]:after {
   content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

Jawr trips over the " (" and the ")". If I remove them, it works fine.

The exception I get when starting tomcat to deploy the web-app is:

```
SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3714)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4085)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Pattern.java:4745)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3694)
    at ... etc etc etc
```

Anybody any idea how to make Jawr eat my original selector without choking? I'm using the latest Jawr 3.3.3

Comment: I think I've also hit this, after I added bootstrap.css to my project - which has that exact fragment of CSS.

Comment: Same here with latest bootstrap 2.3.2 update.  Commenting out 2 instances of "content ..." removes the exception.